# C# How to test this code? BankAccount Class

Tags: c#, class, oop, inheritance, polymorphism

I'm fairly new to C# and was wondering how I can test this sample code. In other words, what do I put in my main (Program.cs) file in order to test the code in the Account.cs (base class) and SavingsAccount.cs (derived class)? I want to pass numbers and have the program output the ToString which is in the Account.cs and SavingsAccount.cs files if that makes sense.

**Account.cs File:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestCode
{
public class Account
{

        protected double interestRate;
        protected string owner;
        protected decimal balance;

        public Account(string o, decimal b, double ir)
        {
            this.interestRate = ir;
            this.owner = o;
            this.balance = b;
        }

        public Account(string o, double ir) :
          this(o, 0.0M, ir)
        {
        }

        public virtual decimal Balance
        {
            get { return balance; }
        }

        public virtual void Withdraw(decimal amount)
        {
            balance -= amount;
        }

        public virtual void Deposit(decimal amount)
        {
            balance += amount;
        }

        public virtual void AddInterests()
        {
            balance += balance * (Decimal)interestRate;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return owner + "'s account holds " +
                  +balance + " kroner";
        }
    }
}
```

**SavingsAccount.cs File:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestCode
{
 public class SavingsAccount : Account
    {

        public SavingsAccount(string o, double ir) :
          base(o, 0.0M, ir)
        {
        }

        public SavingsAccount(string o, decimal b, double ir) :
          base(o, b, ir)
        {
        }

        public override void Withdraw(decimal amount)
        {
            if (amount < balance)
                balance -= amount;
            else
                throw new Exception("Cannot withdraw");
        }

        public override void AddInterests()
        {
            balance = balance + balance * (decimal)interestRate
                              - 100.0M;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return owner + "'s savings account holds " +
                  +balance + " kroner";
        }
    }
}
```

**Program.cs File (What do I write here?):**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestCode
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
     SavingsAccount savingsaccount = new SavingsAccount("John", 0.0M, 0.70);
     savingsaccount.ToString();
    }
}
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I recommend you naming your variables correctly, also in your constructors. It's good practice. If you're going to look at the code in a year it won't make sence if the project has grown large.

Comment: Maybe you should add a `Console.WriteLine(savingsaccount.ToString());` to your Main method. What you are doing is just creating the string but doing nothing with it.

Comment: @Booser Thanks! The Console.WriteLine worked.

Answer (score 1):

```
namespace TestCode
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SavingsAccount account = new SavingsAccount(put,init,values,here);
        account.CallAMethodLikeThis();
    }
}
}
```

Obviously replace `put,init,values,here` and `CallAMethodLikeThis` with actual values and method name.

**Edit**

Now that you've stubbed in this code, replace this:

```
 SavingsAccount savingsaccount = new SavingsAccount("John", 0.0M, 0.70);
 Savingsaccount.ToString();
```

with this:

```
 SavingsAccount savingsaccount = new SavingsAccount("John", 0.0M, 0.70);
 savingsaccount.ToString();
```

The reason is that `SavingsAccount` is the name of your class (the "recipie" for how to make new objects), and `savingsaccount` is the instance you created when you called `new ...`.  `savingsaccount` is the object you use from now on to interact with this copy of the data.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however, when I try that it still won't output anything. I edited my post with what I wrote if you can look at it.

Comment: my mistake, what you mentioned I should do is what I already had. I just accidentally capitalized it when editing my code here. It doesn't output anything for some reason, just says press any key to continue when I ctrl + F5 to run the code.

Comment: `ToString()` is (more-or-less) a reserved method name that has special meaning in .NET.  It's probably better to rename this method to something else -- maybe `ShowBalance` or `Describe` and see if that gives you better output.

Comment: @robrich thats the reason why he is using override to redefine it. What should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Since nowhere in this code is a "press any key to continue" message, you may be running a different project when you push F5 to run.  Right-click on this project, choose "Run as startup project" and try pushing F5 again.  If that doesn't work, right-click on the project, choose properties, and ensure the Startup class is `TestCode.Program`

Comment: I tried that and set the startup object as the TestCode.Program. I even added a Console.ReadLine(); to pause the screen so I don't have to press ctrl + F5. Nothing outputs still. When I tried changing the name ToString to something like Describe, it gives me an error in the Account.cs file which says "no suitable method found to override." However, in the SavingsAccount.cs file when I change ToString to Describe it doesn't give me any errors.

Comment: When you rename the ToString Method to Describe, you must remove the override keyword. Because there is a ToString method to override, which should be perfectly fine there. But there is no Describe method in the base class.

Comment: @Booser Ok, so I tried removing the override key word in the Account.cs base class and it still doesn't output.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you do not use anything to output your string. Add a `Console.WriteLine(savingsaccount.ToString());` to your Main method to not just create the string but write it out to somewhere.

Then the overriding of the ToString methods should also work like they should be used.